when I updated my angular application to v18, tailwind intellisense extension stop works
I was updating my angular application v17 to v18 and I was using tailwind intellisense extension, but after update,  tailwind intellisense extension stop works, I've tried all the solutions on offer, but nothing has worked.
exemple:

classes autocomplete doesn't work.

I solved this by switching my vscode Tailwind extension to the pre release one and then restarting my editor and all intellisense is now back with Angular 18.2

the plugin was updated today and is working normally.
